# Selenium Webdriver: How can I getText() if there's another text within div?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have the following html:

```
<div class="dialog-components">
  <h2 class="dialog-title">
    <div class="help-link">
      <a href="http://google.com">Helps</a>
    </div>
    Expected Result
  </h2>
```

And I want to getText: "Expected Result". But when I tried to:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dialog-components>h2")).getText();
```

The text is "Helps/nExpectedResult".

How can I get my expected text result?

Comment: There should be some tag with "Expected result" text , then only it can be get easily. like <p>Expected result</p>

Comment: @HelpingHands: Yah, I see. But is it possible if we don't have some tags lik e<p> ?
Thank you.

Comment: You can split on the \n and grab the second line. The real problem here is poor development since they are just putting text willy nilly onto the page.

Comment: @PaulDonny - I agree with your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the nodevalue of the element using Javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dialog-components')[0].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue;
```

Use **executescript** to execute JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window

**Below is an example in java**

Don't forget to add return since you need to return the value to the caller

```
String expectedresult = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('dialog-components')[0].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue;");
```

I tested the above code it was working fine

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you have any problems

Comment: @scorpion oh that's gr8....happy to be of help